# How to force user interaction with UIView before continuing?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uiview, uiviewcontroller

With the help of many others on StackOverflow, I finally am able to display a profile screen popover UIView when users tap on a certain face or person.

However, in my app (iOS 6, Xcode 4.6), I also need the popover view to return an index back to the calling ViewController because the next step is using that index to refresh the screen. For example, the user clicks on the top face or image in the main ViewController, and should see a popover that lets the user browse and then choose another image.  When the profile screen is dismissed (from either Cancel or Choose inside the popover), the main screen should update the photo with the one the user chose in the popover.

Right now, I am using the delegate method to get the user's selection in the popover back to the calling ViewController before it dismisses itself.  The problem is when I run my code, the popover doesn't even appear before the calling ViewController moves to the next step and tries using the variable that the profile screen updates before being dismissed.  This is a problem because the variable is junk until the user does something in the popover to update it.

The code works as follows.  First, the user taps on something in the main ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)handleTapFace1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Face 1 tapped!");
    [self showProfileView:0];

    if (returnedSwitchIndex != NO_SWITCH)
    {
        // Animate switch
        [self performVisualSwitch: selectedFaceIndex to:returnedSwitchIndex];
    }
}
```

showProfileView is the function in which I launch a popover profile window, with details on the tapped face, as well as the ability to browse every face for a replacement face.  The popover contains a Cancel UIButton, a Switch UIButton, among the detailed info.

```
-(void) showProfileView: (int) tappedIndex
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    ProfileViewController *profViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileView"];

    // Pass the parameters profView needs to display
    profViewController.currentIndex = tappedIndex;
    profViewController.turnIndex = 0; // <-- TODO: test value

    NSMutableArray* members = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ... load array with candidate faces ...

    profViewController.faces = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:members];

    [self addChildViewController:profViewController];

    profViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548);
    [self.view addSubview: profViewController.view];
    profViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    [profViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    NSLog(@"Self located at: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.view.frame.origin));
    NSLog(@"Frame located at: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(profViewController.view.frame.origin));

    // popup
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
     {
         profViewController.view.alpha = 1;
     }
                     completion:nil];

    // I previous tried to return a value here, that also failed
    //return profViewController.switchIndex;

    // trying to force redisplay before calling ViewController can proceed
    [profViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I guess what I'd like to ask is... "Why isn't the UIView/popover window able to appear before the caller of showProfileView moves forward?" and "How can I force the user to interact with the popped up UIView or UIViewController before the calling ViewController moves beyond the showProfileView line and starts using the returnedSwitchIndex?"  Maybe my delegate solution isn't the way, but then how do I return something from the shown UIView?

Thanks for your help.  Sorry for all the questions.

PS > I chose to use the animate UIView approach because I need the calling ViewController to continue to exist and show up in the background, and it also contains an NSTimer ticking down while the user is working with the popover view. It's okay and desired to have the calling ViewController be there and its NSTimer to continue running, but it's totally bad for it to move forward in code beyond the showProfileView before the view has a chance to actually appear and force user interaction with it (either pressing Cancel button or browsing around and pressing Switch button on another face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you ask for. But you have to understand that UIView manipulations are performed all at once.

So :

The user touch a face :

```
- (IBAction)handleTapFace1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Face 1 tapped!");
    [self showProfileView:0];
}
```

Then you put the callback in another method :

```
- (void)goAhead
{
    if (returnedSwitchIndex != NO_SWITCH)
    {
        // Animate switch
        [self performVisualSwitch: selectedFaceIndex to:returnedSwitchIndex];
    }
}
```

Finally you call the goAhead method when you need (after the user interact with popover) for instance :

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self goAhead];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pull this stuff

```
if (returnedSwitchIndex != NO_SWITCH)
{
    // Animate switch
    [self performVisualSwitch: selectedFaceIndex to:returnedSwitchIndex];
}
```

out into its own method, and set that method as the target when your user Chooses or Cancels. That oughta work.

To get a UIButton to call your method you would do something like this:

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(userDidChoose)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks. The above solution also worked, essentially the same thing, and I'd designate both answers if I could. Thanks again!